# Getting x,y points from image in python-opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I came across below code, where its detecting all the lines by using canny edge detection and hough algorithm. The code below is used to mask the line from where i need to get the points from, but since this is image, i dont know how to get the x and y axis scale(i,e here x1=0,x2=4,y1=0,y2=45) so that in turn i can get the x and y axis points for that masked line. Any approach to do that? Thanks in advance.

Below is the code that I used.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('linearline.png', 1) 
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_range = np.array([18, 100, 100], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_range = np.array([38, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)
edges = cv2.Canny(mask,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
cv2.imshow('edgesimage',edges)


print img.shape[1]
print img.shape
minLineLength=img.shape[1]-300
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges,rho=0.02,theta=np.pi/500,
threshold=10,lines=np.array([]),minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=100)


a,b,c = lines.shape
for i in range(a):
cv2.line(img, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2],       
lines[i][0][3]), (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow('result', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I cant able to upload my linearline.png graph, but its a kind of x-y plot.

Edited : This is the sample image that am using [link](https://images.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.austincc.edu%2F~powens%2F%2BTopics%2FHTML%2F10-2%2Fgraph2.gif&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.keyword-suggestions.com%2FbGluZWFyIGdyb3d0aCBncmFwaA%2F&docid=D6HCGknAGPGdiM&tbnid=8iDbNTA7H9gH9M%3A&vet=1&w=651&h=376&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim#h=376&imgrc=8iDbNTA7H9gH9M:&vet=1&w=651)

Comment: so is your output a line ?

Comment: The output of this code is a masked line, but i need x,y points of that masked line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have them in this line of code:

```
cv2.line(img, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

To get the first coordinate you just have to print:

```
print lines[i][0][0] 
print lines[i][0][1]
```

to get the second coordinate you have to print:

```
print lines[i][0][2] 
print lines[i][0][3]
```

In order to know what `lines` contains type `print lines`

**EDIT:**

Hey MargS, I actually misunderstood what you wanted. To explicitly mention what you wanted you will first have to extract the text in the graph and then identify the spots which makes the expected answer overly broad.

I was however able to identify the line you needed using a different approach.

I converted the image to HSV color space and then extracted the saturation channel. I then applied Hough line transform to get the desired line

CODE:

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)
ret,th = cv2.threshold(s,127,255, 0)
cv2.imshow('th.jpg', th)
```

[image]

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(th,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength=100,maxLineGap=10)
for line in lines:
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = line[0]
    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('houghlines5.jpg',img)
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

Complete code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

filename = 'line.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
cv2.imshow('img.jpg',img)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('gray.jpg',gray)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.imshow('hsv.jpg', hsv)

h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)
ret,th = cv2.threshold(s,127,255, 0)
cv2.imshow('th.jpg', th)

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(th,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength=100,maxLineGap=10)
for line in lines:
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = line[0]
    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow(HoughLines.jpg',img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: ok for that you have to come up with a transformation function. Because in image the origin `(0,0)` starts at the **top left** corner of the image. In graphs it starts at the **bottom-left** corner

Comment: Yeah. What transformation function? Is that any way to get these points?

Comment: @MargS Sorry to keep you waiting... and also sorry for not arriving at the desired expectation. I actually misunderstood what you needed. I hope I can help you in some other way :D

Comment: I am thinking about it in the back of my head. I will let you know once I get some insights. I have upvoted this question as well. :D

Comment: can you pls explain why you have used ret,th = cv2.threshold(s,127,255, 0) line . what it means?

Comment: I converted the image from RGB color space to HSV color space. I obtained the S channel (saturation). Then performed threshold whatever pixel is < 127 -> black, pixels >= 127 -> white

Comment: '0' signifies **black**; meaning everything other than white is black. If you replace '0' with another value like '100', you will end up getting **white** and **grey** image. Try it. :D